# RecyclerView reattaches all views, PublisherAdView in ViewHolder blinks (reloads). Is this normal? How can I avoid this flickering of the ad?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adsense

I have a RecyclerView, with PublisherAdView-s in the ViewHolders.

Whenever I update the VH, it detaches, and then reattaches, which, I assume, is responsible for the PublisherAdView flickering / refreshing / reloading.

(sometimes I can see a resize javascript log in logcat too)

I have checked what happens in the LinearLayoutManager, but I was unable to see anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any solution?

For me, the the solution is to avoid updating the items that contains the ads in the RecyclerView.

You can use the `RecyclerView.notifyItem*` methods to update only non ads items instead of `RecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged`.